# How do you control the selection in "Clump Hair Curves" Node for the "Guide curves" and "Curves to be clumped"?

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves

I've watched the video blender studios have made, but I'm still rather confused on the topic as they quickly go through clumping. How do I control which attributes are "Guide curves" and "Curves to be clumped", and edit them?

I'm trying to use guide curves to create interpolated hair, and then narrow it down to only 1 of the 3 guide hairs clump the generated interpolated hair together. But looking inside the geo-node I'm not too sure what I'm doing in particular.

I've recreated a similar set up in the .blend below, with the hair I am trying to isolate as the sole clumping guide circled.

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood your problem correctly but here is a hair system that uses three guides to create the base hair interpolation and then clumps them around a single guide by removing the toggle for use existing guide map and tweaking the guide mask. The problem with this approach is that the selected guide curve will be more or less randomly selected removing control. For a solution see below the images.

[image]

[image]

To select a specific curve we need to use geometry nodes to set it as the guide curve beforehand. This can be done with the created guide index node group. We need to delete all the curves we don't want as guides and then send the remaining to the guides slot. Woila we have created a new guide map :) It is important that that happens after the interpolated and before the clump.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Ah yes that's exactly what i was looking for! It's a bit of a shame I can't just select a curve and give it a attribute, like selecting a line and giving it a vertex group but this helps out a lot. Thank you so much!